# Is the dk.brics.automaton package thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, fsm, automaton

Apache Lucene [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025332/257122) a modified form of the [Brics](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) automaton package. But is Brics thread safe?

More specifically, can it safely handle multiple, concurrent automaton instances from different threads - without blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, constructing an Automaton or a RunAutomaton from a RegExp is thread safe - unless you use [setAllowMutate](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/dk/brics/automaton/RegExp.html#setAllowMutate%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 1):

thread safety depends upon how you use it, but the way in which we use it doesn't need to be thread safe.

thats because automatonquery's constructor compiles everything to a totally immutable form internally.

Comment: I meant if the same compiled Automaton and then create multiple RunAutomaton instances - one in each thread and then run them concurrently?